# Python, how to create specific classes under a big class

Tags: python, class, text

New python learner here. I'm trying to design a text rpg in python and i want the stats of all the enemy mobs to increase at a specific part of the game. Here is my code for some those enemies:

```
class Executioner:
    def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name

    self.potions = 0
    self.maxhp = 800 
    self.hp = self.maxhp 
    self.attack = 25 
    self.ability = 0 
    self.defense = 0 
    self.goldgain = 333 
    self.expgain = 250 
ExecutionerIG = Executioner("Executioner the slayer")

class Goblin:
    def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name

    self.potions = 0
    self.maxhp = 80
    self.hp = self.maxhp
    self.attack = 25
    self.ability = 0
    self.defense = 0
    self.goldgain = 5.5
    self.expgain = 22
GoblinIG = Goblin("Goblin")

class Zombie:
    def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name

    self.potions = 0
    self.maxhp = 180
    self.hp = self.maxhp
    self.attack = 19    
    self.ability = 0
    self.defense = 0
    self.goldgain = 7
    self.expgain = 28
ZombieIG = Zombie("Zombie")
```

I thought a way to do this quickly can be defining those classes into a big class called enemies and then call enemies.hp, enemies.attack etc to increase.

But i don't know how to do that either as i am quite weeb for now.

Suggestions on how to increase class stats by specifying small classes under a big class or ways to increase class stats quickly(just typing them up and increasing them won't work as i will be having lots of enemy mobs) will be greatly thanked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Daniel Roseman said is true, you should try to not repeat yourself when writing code. If two objects are very similar and only differ in some certain values, then really they are the same object. All bikes are bikes, but some have different wheel sizes for example. Here, your objects are all one Enemy object, and can be implemented as such.

I will however answer your question, because subclassing is very important to know. To subclass a class, you pass in the parent class in a definition, like so:

`class Zombie(Enemy):`

Then if the Enemy class is defined like so for example:

`class Enemy:
  def attack():
    <your code>`

You could call attack on a Zombie object. It will look for attack() in the Zombie class, and if it doesn't find it, it will look for it in the parent class. If it doesn't find it in the parent class it will look for it in that parent's class and so on, moving all the way up to the top level object. If it doesn't find it at all an Exception will be raised. If you defined attack() in the Zombie class for example, then it would overwrite attack() in the Enemy class.

Given all this though, Daniel Roseman is right. You should put all this in one class and pass in hp etc upon construction.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but then again do you know how to do what Daniel Roseman said? To accept those values in the __init__ method for a generic Enemy class? A detailed example would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It's the same as what you have done with the name attribute. So you would have `def __init__(self, name, maxhp, attack, ability, defense, goldgain, expgain): self.name = name self.maxhp = maxhp self.attack = attack self.ability = ability self.defense = defense self.goldgain = goldgain self.expgain = expgain` then you could create a Zombie by doing the following:
`zombie = Enemy("Zombie", 180, 19, 0, 0, 7, 28)`

Answer (score 1):

No, that wouldn't be a good way to do it. Nested classes are rarely useful in Python, and certainly wouldn't be helpful here.

Much better to simply put them into a list you can loop through:

```
enemies = []
...
ExecutionerIG = Executioner("Executioner the slayer")
enemies.append(ExecutionerIG)
```

and so on. Then, when necessary, just iterate:

```
for enemy in enemies:
    enemy.hp += 1
```

As an aside, I would question whether you really need separate classes for Executioner, Zombie and Goblin; they only differ in the numbers for each stat, so perhaps you should just accept those values in the `__init__` method for a generic Enemy class.

Comment: Can you give me a example on "accept those values in the __init__ method for a generic enemy class" What you said i tried doing it but its wrong. What you said was probably correct but i don't know how to do it lol.

Comment: Exactly the same as you've done with the `name` attribute.